# table-of-contents with links to all the .htm files in a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use javascript to open a folder and list html file names in that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620842/how-to-use-javascript-to-open-a-folder-and-list-html-file-names-in-that)

On my local Windows computer, I have a folder with a bunch of .htm files.
I would like to create "table-of-contents.html", which would link to all the .htm files in this folder.

For example, if my folder contains these files:

```
apple.htm
pear.htm
banana.htm
```

then my table-of-contents would contain:

```
<a href="./apple.htm">Apple</a>
<a href="./pear.htm">Pear</a>
<a href="./banana.htm">Banana</a>
```

Of course I could do this manually, but I am looking for a solution that automatically generates the table-of-contents from the current folder.  (This would be a component of a larger script that parses the filenames and reorganizes the links based on the parsed information.)

Any suggestions?  For example, is there a way to use jquery or javascript to generate a list of the htm files in the current folder?

Comment: If your web server is apache, and there is no 'index.htm' or 'index.html' file, this should happen automatically.

Comment: iis does the same thing, if not disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Windows batch script, you could also do:

```
@echo off
echo ^<html^> > toc
for %%i in (*.htm) do echo ^<a href="./%%~nxi"^>%%~ni^</a^> >> toc
echo ^</html^> >> toc
ren toc toc.html
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use awk / gawk.exe  ( http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm ), you could use the following to create the file:

```
dir | gawk.exe 'BEGIN { print "<html>"} { print "<a href=\"./" $1 "\">"$1"</a><br>" } END {print "</html>"}' > directory_listing.html
```

If you're really set on using Javascript, you can probably do something similar in Javascript as well, using regex functions, but would not be able to run it in the browser.